# How to separate the concern of role creation in my controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, separation-of-concerns

After reading some design patterns, I was stuck with the word SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) and I started looking at my controller. I found one example where it may be violating the single responsibility principle. Am I right in saying that the create action should only have the responsibility of making sure whether the object is created or not? I originally put the role creation logic in the same action as well. (i.e. after object is created, add and 'owner' role to the user who created the object).

```
def create
    @car_new_form = CarNewForm.new(current_user)
    if car_id = @car_new_form.submit(params[:car_new_form])
        current_user.add_role :owner, Car.find(car_id)
        redirect_to edit_car_path(car_id)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

I tried moving it into the form object `car_new_form`. However, it seemed that I was only moving the mess elsewhere without solving the separation of concern.

How shall I manage the role management `add_role` considering the separation of concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're currently handling persistence in `CarNewForm`. Consider having a `CreateCar` service, which will be called by `CarNewForm` internally to create your `Car` object.

The responsibilities around car creation (including role assignation) will be handled by this service.

Sample service implementation:

```
class CreateCar
  # service = CreateCar.new(@car, current_user)
  # success_action if service.call

  def initialize(car, owner)
    @car = car
    @owner = owner
  end

  def call
    if @car.save
      owner.add_role(:owner, @car)
      return true 
    end
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: I read a bit about extracting service objects in ruby pattern designs by code-climate. would u be able to write some sample code? thanks!

Comment: @ChrisYeung: Added sample service. This can be called from your controller or from the `NewCarForm`. It might make sense to subsume this into the `NewCarForm` depending on how you define the responsibilities of your form.